# Удалить тег с содержимым регуляркой, в котором есть еще и перенос строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sublime-text

Нужно удалить тег param, в котором есть атрибут name="Особенности" 
Но проблема в том, что в содержимом есть перенос строки

Вот такая регулярка удаляет только строку, где нет переноса
< param id="52287" name="Особенности" >(.+)\s

Как мне удалить все вообще? Работаю в Sublime

**С переносом строки:**

< param id="52287" name="Особенности" >Плечевой ремень из текстиля;
На передней панели скрытый карман на молнии;< /param >

В основном перенос строки после слова с точкой с запятой, но бывает и просто перенос

**Без переноса строки**
     < param id="52287" name="Особенности" >Ручная работа< /param >

Comment: `(?s)<param id="52287" name="Особенности">(.*?)</param>`

Comment: Удаляет четко. Все работает. Благодарю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте

```
(?s)<param id="52287" name="Особенности">(.*?)</param>
```

См. [демо онлайн](https://regex101.com/r/rbtd04/1).

**Подробности**

- `(?s)` - модификатор, изменяющий поведение шаблона `.`, чтобы он находил переносы строки
- `<param id="52287" name="Особенности">` - строка
- `(.*?)` - Захватывающая подмаса (в шаблоне замены можно использовать `$1`): любые 0 и более символов, но как можно меньше
- `</param>` - строка